# Installed Okular using snap, toolbar file open entry don't work

Tags: 16.04, snap, menu, okular

Just installed Okular using the snap package in my ubuntu 16.04 machine.
It works fine if right click a pdf and choose open with->okular.
If I open Okular I cannot use the file menu in the toolbar. If click "Open.." nothing happens and have no error in dmesg, no error displayed.
I am a newbie so please tell me if need you any further information, I will provide. Thank you.
If can help I had Okular previously installed using apt (which if I remember well version 0.24), perfectly working, just wanted to try latest version (1.7.2)
Any Idea?

EDIT

Seems that the problem is related to filesystem permissions because the only menu entries that are not working (clicking them nothing happen) are those one that should open a file dialog, so File->Open, File->Import.., File->Save As, File->Export As.. while File->Print and File->Properties for example are working.
I have other packages installed with snap, for example VLC, that are working flawless.

Comment: I have the same problem two years later. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: As reported by answer the problem is gone with a OS kernel update. Right now I still have Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.15.0-189-generic and Okular 21.04.1 is working fine..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the kernels between 4.4.0-155-generic and 4.4.0-157-generic solved the issue, as the rest is the same and now everything is working.