# Okular (Snap & Flatpak) problem with inverse search

Tags: snap, emacs, okular, flatpak

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, and the **Okular** versions available to me seem to be the following:

- apt: 20.04.0
- snap: 20.12.3
- flatpak: 22.04.03

I would like a version > 20.12, because that [allows me to disable smooth scrolling](https://www.mail-archive.com/okular-devel@kde.org/msg36888.html). This rules out the apt version.

I would also like to be able to do direct and inverse search with Emacs. The snap and flatpak version have different problems with this:

**Flatpak**: Emacs is not able to launch Okular opening the pdf at the appropriate page. As I've learned from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1223266/1519798) and [this question and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451113/515980), this is because there's no simple `okular` command available on the command line; and even creating an alias has problems with extra arguments. (It seems Okular is just not the kind of application one should install from Flatpak.) On the other hand, reverse-search works fine.

**Snap**: In this case the direct search works well (pdf opened at appropriate page), but the inverse search doesn't work. Shift-clicking on the pdf document (with browse tool activated, as [explained in this question & answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/145567/1519798)) does not do anything at all. [Edit: this seems to be related to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1157934/1519798), since I don't manage to bring up the "Open..." menu dialogue either.]

I wonder if someone can help me in solving either the problem with the Flatpak version, or the one with the Snap version, or propose an alternative solution. Let me add that I also tried to [install Okular from source](https://okular.kde.org/build-it/), but I get one error after another from `cmake` and dependencies, of which I understand very little.